# Using pointer to base class to access derived class and vice-versa

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I have the following hierarchy

```
class A {
…
}
class B: public A{
…
}
class C: public B {
…
}
```

```
void foo()
{
auto* bar = dynamic_cast<C*> getPointerToInsanceOfA();
//use bar as if it were a pointer to object of derived class C.
}
```

I tried this, it works as expected.

How about foo1?

```
void foo1()
{
Auto* bar1 = dynamic_cast<A*> getPointerToInsanceOfC();
//use bar1 as if it were a pointer to object of base class A .
}
```

Are there any pitfalls wrt to object splicing or anything else in either cases.

Comment: There's no need to perform a dynamic cast (or any sort of cast) when converting from a pointer-to-derived class to a pointer-to-base class.  That will be done implicitly when it is valid to do so.

Comment: With pointer casting no object splicing happens ever. Casting derived pointer to base pointer is free, no need for dynamic_cast. Although in order to access derived class from base class you need some form of virtuality. Casting base pointer to derived via dynamic_cast generates a runtime overhead (and will return nullptr if the cast is invalid). Other than that no hidden pitfalls are there.

Comment: There's no object slicing here as you are using pointers rather than copying objects.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm got it. so dynamic cast is needed for foo but not for foo1. thanks!

Comment: @freakish that makes sense to me now. Thank you.

Comment: @freakish yes, I meant dynamic_cast<C*>. Sorry, will edit.